# Laravel query builder doesn't use apostrophe in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When validating with the expression `unique` in my custom request, laravel builds a query in such a way that my DBMS (Mysql 8.0) cannot execute it. Laravel does not use apostrophes in WHERE expressions and in others expressions. How can I fix this problem?

**Validation request:**

```php
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "nickname" => ["required", "min:3", "max:16"],
            "uuid" => ["required", "uuid", "unique:players"]
        ];
    }
```

**Mysql:**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `players` where `uuid` = c3c7345c-cd1f-4f8b-a41c-61d7b7740065) in file C:\Users\1\Documents\sites\laravel\monitoring-core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 760
```

[Query with apostrophes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SybkD.png)

[Query without apostrophes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao1B6.png)

I tried to modify Laravel Builder, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: The error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]` is actually `Connection Refused`. Can you check if you're using the correct DB credentials?

Comment: check connection. this has nothing to do with apostrophe.